# How to tell the eclipse that a certain file is a makefile

Tags: eclipse

I remember there was a way to specify a  certain file as a makefile so the editor to visualize the text in appropriate manner. How was that possible? 
Excuse my poor English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can associate files to specific editors through Windows->Preferences->General->Editors->File Associations

Comment: This is what I have been looking for :)